# Infinite loop in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, infinite

While making a link Shortner script using nodejs, i encountered the following problem:
my program went on an infinite loop for a reason i ignore
here is the code:

```
function makeShort() {
    var short = "";
    var cond = true;

    while(cond){
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
            short += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        let query = {short:short};

        Link.findOne(query, (err, link)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!link){
                console.log("here");
                cond = false;

            }
        });
    }
    return short;
}
```

to then use it here :

```
router.post('/', (req, res)=>{
    let short = makeShort();
    const newLink = new Link({
        url: req.body.url,
        short:short
    });

    newLink.save().then(link => {
        res.json(link);
    });
});
```

the idea is that i generate a random string (5 characters), and then, if it exists i create another one and so on.. until i find one that isn't used ( the database is empty btw so there is no reason for it to go infinite loop ).

Comment: Its looping infinitely in the `for` loop because `length` isn't defined

Comment: So change `length` in for the `for` loop to 5 or another length you want the string to be

Comment: looks like cond = true is out of scope with var cond = false

Comment: I might be wrong, but wont `findOne` get called many times until `cond == false` since it runs a callback?

Comment: Also, you can replace your for loop with this: `short = (Math.random() * 1000).toString(32).replace(/\./g, '').substr(0, length)`

Comment: Your while loop and those Link.findOne do not resolve synchronously: your while loop is going to trigger _a million times_ while Link.findOne is still looking for the first result.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans okay, and how to fix that ? i mean like how do i stop the first loop from triggering while searching in the database ?

Comment: use `await/async`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn okay thanks i'll search for it

Comment: @IlyesYamoun By writing your logic based on the fact that you're going to get results "at some point". see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over and test for values in your database using `async/await`. What we do is convert your function to an async function, then create a new function that will return a promise which will resolve `true/false`.

Next we call that function in the while loop and `await` for a result which will contain `true/false` we then set that to the variable `cond` and continue the loop.

It would look something like this:

```
async function makeShort(length) {
  let cond = true;

  while (cond) {
    let short = (Math.random() * 1000).toString(32).replace(/\./g, '').substr(0, length);

    let query = { short: short };
    cond = await findOne(query);
  }
  return short;
}

function findOne(query) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    Link.findOne(query, (err, link) => {
      if (err) resolve(false);
      if (!link) {
        return resolve(false);
      }
      return resolve(true);
    });
  })
}
```

We then can call it using `let short = await makeShort()` like this (we also have to the make `(req, res)` function `async`):

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let short = await makeShort();
  const newLink = new Link({
    url: req.body.url,
    short: short
  });

  newLink.save().then(link => {
    res.json(link);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix synchronous looping and asynchronous condition updating. Something like this is guaranteed to run the `while` body as many times as it can before that `DoSomething` call returns a result:

```
while(cond) {
  // call something async. don't wait for a result.
  DoSomething.asynchronous( () => { cond = false; });
  // then immediately restart the iteration
}
```

So don't do that. Make your `makeShort` generate a shortform string asynchronously.

```
const symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
const symbolCount = symbols.length;

function makeShort(howMany) {
  howMany = howMany || 5;
  let short = "";
  while(howMany--) {
    short += symbols[(Math.random() * symbolCount)|0];
  }
  return short;
}
```

Then, do your verification independently of this:

```
function assignShortForm(req, res) {
  let short = makeShort();

  verifyShortIsAvailable(
    short,
    success => {
      // this short form was available
      new Link({ url: req.body.url, short }).save().then(link => res.json(link));
    }, error => {
      // try again. RNG is not your friend, and this COULD run a very long time.
      assignShortForm(req, res);          
    }
  );
}
```

With your router using that function, not inlining it:

```
router.post('/', assignShortForm);
```

In this, verifyShortIsAvailable should do its work asynchronously:

```
verify verifyShortIsAvailable(short, resolve, reject) {
  Link.findOne(query, (err, link) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    if (link) return reject("...");
    return resolve();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`while` loops run synchronously, meaning they block the thread from further execution until they are complete. Because the link shortener is asynchronous, it is being blocked by the `while` loop.

To handle this code asynchronously, you can return a `Promise`

```
function makeShort() {

    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    // note length was previously undefined in the comparison. use possible.length or another arbitrary value
    for(var i = 0; i < possible.length; i++){
        short += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }

    let query = {short:short};
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Link.findOne(query, (err, link) => {
            if(err) return reject(err);
            resolve(link)
        });
    })
}
```

Then you can use it like so...

```
let short = makeShort().then(shortLink => {
    // do something with the link
}).catch(err => {
    // handle the error
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises